# onchange and onreset handlers not updating css properties on reset

Tags: javascript, css, forms, onchange, reset

I have a form (which I am incidentally generating in PHP from a database) that is using CSS to replace checkboxes. When a `checkbox` is checked, the containing `<li>` should have an `outline` added, and when unchecked, the outline should be removed. Using `onchange` events works to change these at a click, but the outlines remain when the form is reset. I added `onreset` events, to try to force the removal, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

I've recreated this behavior in the snippet. (I have not hidden the checkboxes, as the snippet system apparently does not duplicate the normal browser behavior of clicking on the `<label>` to set or clear the checkbox. [EDIT: This was my mistake; I set the wrong `for` on the labels, and now that behavior works. The rest stands.])

How do I make this work?  I could have a function that manually sets each `outline` in a reset function, but, as I said, the checkboxes are created from a database, so I'd have to write the PHP to write the js function, which seems like the wrong way to go.

```js
function doCheckboxes(clicked_id) {
  if (document.getElementById(clicked_id).checked) {
    document.getElementById(clicked_id).parentNode.style.outline = "2px solid black";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(clicked_id).parentNode.style.outline = "0 none black";
  }
}

function clearCheckboxes(clicked_id) {
  document.getElementById(clicked_id).parentNode.style.outline = "0 none black";
}
```

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.imageholder {
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: auto;
}

.has-thing1 .imageholder {
  background-image: url(path/to/image.png);
}

.has-thing2 .imageholder {
  background-image: url(path/to/image.png);
}

.has-thing3 .imageholder {
  background-image: url(path/to/image.png);
}
```

```html
<form action="." method="get">
  <fieldset class="subcategory">
    <ul>
      <li class="has-x has-thing1">
        <input type="checkbox" onChange="doCheckboxes(this.id)" onReset="clearCheckboxes(this.id)" id="x_thing1" name="has[]" value="thing1">
        <label for="x_thing1">
        <div class="imageholder">&nbsp;</div>
        Thing1
      </label>
      </li>
      <li class="has-x has-thing2">
        <input type="checkbox" onChange="doCheckboxes(this.id)" onReset="clearCheckboxes(this.id)" id="x_thing2" name="has[]" value="thing2">
        <label for="x_thing2">
        <div class="imageholder">&nbsp;</div>
        Thing2
      </label>
      </li>
      <li class="has-x has-thing3">
        <input type="checkbox" onChange="doCheckboxes(this.id)" onReset="clearCheckboxes(this.id)" id="x_thing3" name="has[]" value="thing3">
        <label for="x_thing3">
        <div class="imageholder">&nbsp;</div>
        Thing3
      </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button></div>
  <button type="reset">Clear Selection</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create function clearAllCheckboxes

```
  function clearAllCheckboxes(evt) {
    const formEl = evt.closest('form')
    const allCheckbox = formEl.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]')
    allCheckbox.forEach(checkbox => {
      checkbox.parentNode.style.outline = "0 none black"
    })
  }
```

Add an onClick handler to the button "Clear Selection"

```
<button type="reset" onClick="clearAllCheckboxes(this)">Clear Selection</button>
```

Comment: This is sort of what i was hoping to avoid, as the final form has not just (the equivalent of)  has-x but also has-a, has-b, has-c, et c. It may, however, be the only way to go. Thanks.

Comment: Ah!  Of course, that makes sense. Thank you!